# RabbitMQ nodes not accepting more work

Tags: c#, mono, rabbitmq

I'm working with RabbitMQ in C# right now.  My Rabbit code is 100% the same as to what is seen on the tutorial page here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html .  Before when I started up about 5 workers, they all were accepting new messages at first, but then after some time, only 2 of the workers were accepting new messages, then only 1.

I'm not sure what the cause is here.  The nodes that don't accept any new messages.  They do ACK to the server when their last job is complete.

Also, all of my nodes do use the same username and password, is that a good practice?  Or might that be the cause of my issue here?

Comment: Didn't really understand `The nodes that don't accept any new messages do ACK to the server when their last job is complete.` Are you doing auto ack, or manual/explicit? The same username and password is not the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally forgot two words.

Comment: Again, I didn't understand what do you mean by nodes. So, I'm gonna assume it's clients, since nodes in this context would mean instances of rabbitmq broker. Anyhow could it be simply that the the clients hang and don't actually do the ACK ? You can check in the web UI the number of unacked messages.

Comment: Couple of questions. 1. What is your pre fetch value per consumer? 2. Are there still messages available on the queue or is the 1 worker keeping up by consuming them all?

Comment: Prefetch value is just 1, yes, there are still a lot of messages on the queue (e.g. I kill the application and then restart it, and it starts accepting messages again).  I don't think one worker is hogging them.